# Servlet to Servlet Communication

Tags: java, servlets

I'm making a Java Web Application but I'm newbie in Java.

I have a Servlet (/locatemodules) that try to find other servlets in the server (/modules/*), currently the servlet find the name of the other servlets (/modules/logout, /modules/invoice, etc),  but I need to get some properties and call methods to the discovered servlets, the properties and methods are the same in all servlets.

Calling like: `discoveredServlet.getMenuItem();`

getMenuItem returns some values, menuName, menuUrl, sideMenu[], sideUrl[], etc... to make a menu item in the web application dinamically, the discovered servlets has the post and get for when is called on the main menu.

I'm find Inter Servlet Communication articles, but unfourtunally doesn't work with API 2.2 and later.

How can get a solution like this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Loaded extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                           throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    Enumeration names = context.getServletNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
      String name = (String)names.nextElement();
      Servlet servlet = context.getServlet(name);
      out.println("Servlet name: " + name);
      out.println("Servlet class: " + servlet.getClass().getName());
      out.println("Servlet info: " + servlet.getServletInfo());
      out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a design principle, Servlets should only be used to receive requests from the container, invoke classes that contain business logic, and redirect to a JSP that shows the response ([MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). All the business logic should be on clases that are decoupled from the HTTP protocol.

So, I think the best thing you could do, is to remove these menu related methods from your servlets, put them on [POJOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), and invoke this POJOs from your servlets.

Also, remember that normally, Servlets are Singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are the classes that are supposed to accept requests on servers and respond them.

As you are making an HTTPServlet so it is supposed to accept an http request via http methods like `get` and `post` (so you get methods `doGet()` and `doPost()` in servlets), and then servlet processes the request and sends the http response.

If you want to communicate between servers then you should set some attributes using `setAttribute()` method and then `redirect` (using response.sendRedirect()) or forward your request to another servlet and use `getAttribute()` method to receive values.

Servlets are not meant to be used like normal classes, that you make objects of servlet class and call its methods.